# Select and update SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am extracting data using the query below, which pulls about 200 users.

```
Select 
    users.user_id, users.first_name, users.last_name,
    user_profiles.role, user_profiles.last_modified, 
    user_profiles.last_modified_by
From
    users
Inner Join
    user_profiles on user_profiles.user_id = users.user_id
Where 
    project_id = '28'
    and role like 'customer__bread__fsubmit__fedit__bdefault'
order by 
    last_modified
```

I now want to update the role to a new role of :

```
IBS__bGlobal__bCustomer__b__P__bTLO__b__p
```

How can I incorporate that role into the select query?

Your assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: (1) Qualify all the column names so readers can understand your query.  (2) Tag your question with the database you are actually using.

Comment: Do you want to update database or change the select so that it returns other data?

Comment: @GordonLinoff the tables are: 1. users and 2. user_profiles. regarding database being used i am using SQL 2008 r2. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way

```
UPDATE up
SET    up.role = 'IBS__bGlobal__bCustomer__b__P__bTLO__b__p'
FROM   users u
       INNER JOIN user_profiles up
               ON up.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE  project_id = '28'
       AND up.role = 'customer__bread__fsubmit__fedit__bdefault'
```

Also when you don't need wildcard search then use `=` instead of `Like`